# I currently have a stored procedure that contains 5 joins, would it be more efficient to implement it as a view?

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb, view

My current stored procedure is badly written and needs to be refactored. I've managed to find the time to do that. 
This procedure will be called every two minutes or so, and as more products are sold the results table will get bigger.

Would it be more efficient to implement a view with all the details I require and just run a `SELECT` statement based on that, or is it better to keep it as a stored procedure?

The stored procedure currently checks other views, but they are not tailored to my specific needs and so contain a lot of other data I don't need.

Comment: Why do you use a stored procedure at all instead of just the proper statement? If it is called from many places then you can usually do one "service" in your application which will be responsible for it and call that instead.

Comment: It's a complex statement. I was under the impression that stored procedures were more efficient; and generally complex queries like that look really ugly in code.

Comment: In some other RDBMS stored procedures often are the way to go. But in MySQL/MariaDB there are some problems with them - the code is "compiled" per connection, so the usual "it is being precompiled and cached" argument does not hold - they are very hard to debug (in sql server I was able to go step by step with a debugger, in mysql it is a problem to at least get current value of any variable). Complex queries are ugly anywhere and in app code you can work with them, modify them dynamically etc which is really cumbersome in SP and breaks caching even more.

Comment: OK, that's interesting about the compiled per connection thing, and I agree with you about manipulating statements in code - I've done that elsewhere. So there's no advantage in having this as a view given it's going to be queried so regularly and with the same parameter?

Comment: If you have one specific query and no "moving parts" then it should work well, but the problem with views is that for some definitions it is not possible to use the "merge" strategy or even if it is, the optimizer might still not optimize it as well - doing `select a from W where x=1` which expands to `select a from (select a,b,c from table1 join table2... where x IN (<a lot of things>)) where x=1` may in many cases (and if the view contains group by etc then in all cases) create a derived table with a,b,c and many x, from which the "main" select gets only a tiny portion in the end.

Comment: ^ this may or may not apply for your use case though